# MySQL avoid data repetitions for select statement

Tags: mysql

MySQL avoid data repetitions for select statement. See the example below

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you are using so it is easier to fix.

Comment: Tip 1. In sample code, use different scales for different concepts, so taxid might be 1001,1002,1003, and productid might be 1,2,3. Tip 2. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

When querying data from a table, you may get duplicate rows. In order to remove these duplicate rows, you use the DISTINCT clause in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select th.TxnID,th.TxnAmount,ti.ProductID,ti.itemPrice from TRANHEADS th LEFTJOIN TRANITEMS ti on th.TxnID = ti.TxnID GROUP BY th.TxnID;
```